# Spring JPA native subquery is not working , returning zero record

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

i am trying to execute below sub query in spring jpa, but it is returning 0 records, but same query is returning records in this link [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9e6f08dee1df690dd53fe5d727a2b7ac)

```
    @Query(value = " SELECT id FROM (SELECT *, SUM(total_quantity) OVER (ORDER BY created_dttm DESC) "
        + "- total_quantity AS tq_sum FROM t) sub_query WHERE type= ?1 and tq_sum < ?2", nativeQuery = true)
     public List<LubricantStock> findAllLubeStockForLubeTypeAndTotalQuantity(int lube_type_id, double total_quatity);
```

is there any limitations using subquery in spring jpa

Comment: `tq_sum` is an `integer` not a `double`. So you have a type mismatch there and your query isn't complete (your query in the fiddle sample is slightly different with more columns).  To map to a DTO you have to make sure the column names match else it won't work afaik.

Comment: tq_sum is double only, even if i pass tq_sum as integer, the query returns 0 only